# Exporting functions in a dll. C and C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have an application called ProCharts that could read and access files from a C++ dll. Now
if I add something like this and compile the dll in x64 mode.(VS2010->Win32 Console App->DLL)

```
int __stdcall Testb(int v)
{
    return v;
}
```

and then define that in a **def** file .The function gets called from that App with no problems.

However if I have something like this function in the same file (its name is also present in the def file)

```
int __stdcall AdvancedFunction(int v)
{
          //Calling a library that requires other libraries such as boost
          return ..;
}
```

then even the first function does not get called and the application calling the dll only states that there is an error with the dll. Could anyone tell me what might be going wrong ?I have placed all the dependencies with the dll file however I am still getting an error.
I used dependency checker and it states that two functions are c functions and not C++ any suggestions or hints on how I could resolve this issue would highly be appreciated.

Comment: To start with maybe you could post _what_ the error you get is?

Comment: Did you try using `__declspec(dllexport)`, `__declspec(dllimport)`? Should be easier than maintaining separate _def_ file

Comment: @JoachimPileborg like I said the program that I am using is not that informative and I only get a message saying "Cannot read the dll file" which means there is something wrong with the dll.

Comment: @PavelZhuravlev the manual for that app states that we should use __stdcall

Comment: @Casper_2211 It could also be that there is something wrong with the program. I would try writing your own program to call the extra function in your DLL. If you can manage that then maybe the fault is with the program you are using. If not then you might get some more clues as to the mistake you are making.

Comment: @john I wrote my own C++ component and the dll function works well with it. But not with that program. Any suggestions on how I could get an idea on whats going on inside the program ?

Comment: @Casper_2211 I don't see why you can't use both `__declspec()` and `__stdcall` in declaration. Also, did you try to compare your dll's (one which works and one which does not) using `depends.exe`? Try to compare function names and ordinals in dlls. It may give you some additional clues. By the way, a function will be marked "C++" if it has a mangled name. So, if you have a function containing C++ code with unmangled name it will still be marked as "C" by `depends.exe`.

Comment: @Casper_2211 Unless you have the source everything is guess work. How do you tell ProCharts where you dll is? Presumably ProCharts is calling LoadLibrary to find the dll. Does your application do that or do you use an import library? Are there any differences in the dependencies your DLL has when you do and don't use the third party libraries? In particular I'd look at dependencies on the CRT and try different options there. Finally you could at a DllMain to your DLL and try logging calls to that function. It might provide some clues.

Comment: ProCharts uses a language called "Easy language" we point it to the dll and the function parameters

Comment: @Casper_2211 is it feasible your DLL is dependent on any *other* DLL's that may not be potentially in the loader-path at the time ProCharts (from wherever its current working directory is) is trying to load your lib?

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for the suggestion so i pasted the files(dependencies) in the application folder and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

After pasting the dependency and the other dll files in the main folder of ProCharts my library worked.

Comment: Excellent you're up and running. glad to help.